# Geometric and arithmetic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let a,b and c be consecutive terms in a geometric sequence and a, 2b and c be consecutive terms in an arithmetic sequence. Determine the quotient b/a.

$a,2b,c$ arithmetic sequence

$2b=a+d$ and $c=a+2d$

And, $a+2b+c=3(a+c)/2\leftrightarrow2a+4b+2c=3a+3c\leftrightarrow$
$4b=a+c$

$a,b,c$ geometric sequence

$b=ar$ and $c=ar^{2}$

And, $a+b+c=\frac{a(1-r^{3})}{1-r}$

Came to this first:

$\frac{b}{a}=\frac{c}{b}$

$\frac{b}{a}=\frac{4b-a}{b}$

$\frac{b}{a}=4-\frac{a}{b}$

$\frac{b}{a}+\frac{a}{b}=4$

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  Write down the two equations that corresond to each condition (one geometric sequence, one arithmetic sequence).  You will most likely see how to solve this with that initial effort.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! With questions likes these (resembling homework), we first expect some effort from the asker before we help out.

Comment: $a, b=ar, c=ar^2$ and $a, 2b=a+d, c=a+2d$ ... & then I tried ??? Come on Jimmy.

Comment: You can absolutely use latex.  And, please add your work to the original post, rather than as a comment.

Comment: Ok original post updated and latex seems to work fine.

Comment: $ac=b^2$ and $a+c=2b$ ... we are aiming for $a/b$ ... $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{b}{c}$ and $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{b}=2$ ... Come on Jimmy ... nearly there ...

Comment: Oops $a+c=4b$ and $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{b}=4$ ... Sorry Jimmy

Comment: This is what I did earlier, just ended with: $\frac{b}{a}=\frac{c}{b}$

$\frac{b}{a}=\frac{4b-a}{b}$

$\frac{b}{a}=4-\frac{a}{b}$

$\frac{b}{a}+\frac{a}{b}=4$

Answer (score 1):

$2b-a = d\\
c - 2b = d\\
c - a = 2d\\
c+a = 4b$

That is about as much as we can say right now about the arithmetic sequence.  Lets look at the geometric sequence.

$\frac {b}{a} = r\\
\frac {c}{b} = r^2\\
b = ar\\
c = ar^2$

We want to solve for $r$
Substitute: $b= ar, c=ar^2$ into $a+c = 4b$

$ar^2+a = 4ar\\
a(r^2 - 4r + 1) = 0$

Use the quadratic formula to solve for $r.$